# Termination test in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form. Program crashes

Tags: c++, for-loop, openmp

I am getting the error message: "termination test in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form" on this code and I don't know why.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 1; i >= 1 && i < 100000; i++)
{
    Sum[i] = 0;

    for (int j = 1; j >= 1 && j < i; j++)
    {
        if (i % j == 0)
        {
            Sum[i] = Sum[i] + j;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: you will not get in that inner loop in the first iteration, when i == j == 1

Comment: And by "program crashes" you mean "compilation gets aborted", don't you?

Answer (score 1):

What do you need (i >= 1) and (j >= 1) for? I think that this might be your problem, try removing these conditions